# how to set xcodebuild archive name and path

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

im using xcodebuild to automate my release process and would like to first do an:

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme archive
```

and then build the ipa.

the problem is that xcodebuild puts the xcarchive is some obscure location and maes it include the date.

my question:

how can i override/force xcodebuild to name and place the acrhive whene i want it to go (/tmp)?

i tried:

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyApp archive ARCHIVE_PATH='/tmp'
```

but that didn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme archive -archivePath "/tmp"
```